# How to make column counter that will show when the value in other column change

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column "status" in dataframe that has following values:

```
increase
increase
increase
increase
decline
decline
decline
increase
increase
decline
```

I need to make counter that will change each time the value in column 'status' change from decline to increase.
It should look like this:

```
"status"          "counter"
increase          1
increase          1
increase          1
increase          1
decline           2
decline           2
decline           2
increase          3
increase          3
decline           4
```

What is appropriate way to do it in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a boolean then just apply a cumulative sum.

```
df['counter'] = df['status'].ne(df['status'].shift()).cumsum() 

  status  counter
0  increase        1
1  increase        1
2  increase        1
3  increase        1
4   decline        2
5   decline        2
6   decline        2
7  increase        3
8  increase        3
9   decline        4
```

​

Comment: @KaterynaLubyk no problemo, I didn't add much of an explanation since the code is quite simple but let me know if you need any additional detail. don't forget to accept the answer :)